# Javascript Loop - can't figure this one out

Tags: javascript, loops

I've tried everything that crossed my mind, but no luck with this loop (although i'm pretty new to javascript).
Prompt should ask a question until nothing entered. At that point all the 'results' that were previously entered should be taken and processed.
Result should look like (if entered for 1st prompt: 'CS A 4', 2nd 'BB B 3', 3rd 'CC C 3'..):....showing only after there was not entry for nth prompt

```
COURSE GRADE HOURS  
CS     A     4  
BB     B     3  
CC     C     3
```

---

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>gpa.html</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getData(){
        var input=0,
            results=[];

        while(input!==""){input = prompt("Enter course name, grade and credit hours (e.g., 'CS3520 A 4' or click OK with no data to terminate.");
        input = input.split(" ");
        if(input==""){
        results.push({
            course: input[0].trim(),
            grade: input[1].trim(),
            creditHours: parseInt(input[2], 10)
        });}}
        return results;         
    }

    var app = function() {
        var result, results,
        COLUMN_SEPARATOR = "\t\t";

        document.writeln("<pre>");
        results = getData();

        document.writeln("COURSE" + COLUMN_SEPARATOR + "GRADE" + COLUMN_SEPARATOR + "HOURS");
        for (var i = 0, j = results.length; i < j; i++) {
            result = results[i];

            document.writeln(result.course + COLUMN_SEPARATOR + result.grade + COLUMN_SEPARATOR + result.creditHours);
        }   

        document.writeln();
        computeGPA(results);
        document.writeln("</pre>");    
    }

window.onload = app;

</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where exaclty is that you are getting this loop?

Comment: shouldn't `if(input==""){` in your `getData` function be something along the lines of `if(input.length){`? I don't think your current statement will ever be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed (below the split): `if(input=="")`

Added (above the split): `if (input === "") { break; }`

This should do it:

```
function getData() {
    var input = 0,
        results = [];

    while (input !== "") {
        input = prompt("Enter course name, grade and credit hours (e.g., 'CS3520 A 4' or click OK with no data to terminate.");
        if (input === "") { break; }
        input = input.split(" ");

        results.push({
            course: input[0].trim(),
            grade: input[1].trim(),
            creditHours: parseInt(input[2], 10)
        });

    }
    return results;
}



var app = function () {
    var result, results,
    COLUMN_SEPARATOR = "\t\t";

    document.writeln("<pre>");
    results = getData();

    document.writeln("COURSE" + COLUMN_SEPARATOR + "GRADE" + COLUMN_SEPARATOR + "HOURS");
    for (var i = 0, j = results.length; i < j; i++) {
        result = results[i];

        document.writeln(result.course + COLUMN_SEPARATOR + result.grade + COLUMN_SEPARATOR + result.creditHours);
    }

    document.writeln();
    document.writeln("</pre>");
}
```

But i think that this would be an even better solution:

```
function getData() {
    var input = true,
        results = [];

    while (input) {
        input = prompt("Enter course name, grade and credit hours (e.g., 'CS3520 A 4' or click OK with no data to terminate.");
        if (!input) { break; }
        input = input.split(" ");

        results.push({
            course: input[0].trim(),
            grade: input[1].trim(),
            creditHours: parseInt(input[2], 10)
        });

    }
    return results;
}

var app = function () {
    var result, results,
    COLUMN_SEPARATOR = "\t\t";

    document.writeln("<pre>");
    results = getData();

    document.writeln("COURSE" + COLUMN_SEPARATOR + "GRADE" + COLUMN_SEPARATOR + "HOURS");
    for (var i = 0, j = results.length; i < j; i++) {
        result = results[i];

        document.writeln(result.course + COLUMN_SEPARATOR + result.grade + COLUMN_SEPARATOR + result.creditHours);
    }

    document.writeln();
    document.writeln("</pre>");
}
```

Because the return value of canceled prompt() depends on the browser. In most browsers the return value is null. However, some very old browsers (e.g. early versions of IE) used to return '' (an empty string).

So instead of using something like `if (input != '' && input != null)`, just use true or false.

User pressed OK, but the input field was empty `input === ""`

User typed something and hit OK (or enter) `input == true`

User pressed CANCEL `input == null` or `input == ""`

**UPDATE**

About the `textarea` thing, try something like this (i didn't test it):

```
textareaContentByLines = textareaContent.split("\n");

for(index = 0; index < textareaContentByLines.length; index++){
    input = textareaContentByLines.split(" ");
    results.push({
                course: textareaContentByLines[index][0].trim(),
                grade: textareaContentByLines[index][1].trim(),
                creditHours: parseInt(textareaContentByLines[index][2], 10)
            });
}
```

Comment: @peter   Hmm, another thing if i may ask :-). Similar scenario as above, if i have a text area  instead of prompt and each course, grade and hours are separated by a new line, how can i read and create subarrays course, grade, hours from each line and use it later on for other things.

Comment: First you split the value of the `textarea` for every new line and then you split each line like you did before. I have added an example for the  `textarea` in at the bottom of my answer.